# request_irq returns -16 (-EBUSY)

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, irq

Here is my problem. I'm currently updating the kernel of an arm embedded Linux machine, going from **4.1** to **4.14.73**.

I'm facing a problem with a driver. With kernel 4.1, right before registering the irq with `request_irq`, the flag `IRQF_VALID` would be set for the driver by `set_irq_flags`.

As documented [here](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/6772661/),

> set_irq_flags is ARM specific with custom flags which have genirq
>   equivalents. Convert drivers to use the genirq interfaces directly, so
>   we can kill off set_irq_flags. The translation of flags is as follows:
>
> `IRQF_VALID` -> `!IRQ_NOREQUEST`
>
> `IRQF_PROBE` -> `!IRQ_NOPROBE`
>
> `IRQF_NOAUTOEN` -> `IRQ_NOAUTOEN`

Consequently, I replaced `set_irq_flags` with an `irq_clear_status_flags(irq, IRQ_NOREQUEST)`.

Thing is, now the `request_irq` call returns `-16` (`-EBUSY`), and I have no idea why. I checked every single irq being requested (at runtime), and they are all different from the one requested by this driver.

I also noticed this line on the log:

> genirq: Flags mismatch irq 40. 00000004 (digitalGPIO) vs. 00000000 ((null))

I'm very puzzled from the `(null)` device name.

What am I doing wrong?

I hope I included enough context informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, as obvious, the IRQ was indeed already registered as `not shared` way before my module was being loaded.

This was due to a change in the kernel I'm using, which is an Altera revision *based* on the linux kernel. They changed the behaviour of the driver associated to this IRQ in a previous kernel update.

What I can't understand is why the previous request was being logged as `(null)` instead of the correct name. The only way to show the correct informations about who previously requested the IRQ would be to set it as `shared` directly in the Altera kernel.